# Types of generating functions (ordinary, exponential, ???) closed under substitution

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

A nice feature of ordinary and exponential generating functions is that they are closed under substitution:  if $F(z)$ and $G(z)$ both have integer coefficients, then $F(G(z))$ also has integer coefficients.

So, for which sequences $a_n$ are the coefficients of $F(G(z))$ integer multiples of $1/a_n$, where $F(z)=\sum f_n z^n/a_n$, $G(z)=\sum g_n z^n/a_n$ and $f_n$ and $g_n$ are integer sequences?

I know of $a_n = x^{n-1}$ and $a_n = x^{n-1} n!$ (but I do not know of any applications of these either).

**Update**: thanks to Alexander Burstein's comment and Oleksandr Kulkov's answer, I now have a vast supply of such sequences, two of which I find particularly interesting:

- $a_n = (n-1)!$
- $a_n = \phi(1)\dots\phi(n-1)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient, the number of smaller integers coprime to the argument.

I'd be interested in applications of these, too.

Comment: I think Fibotorials would work, too, and probably other factorial-like sequences similarly constructed.

Comment: Indeed, $a_1=a_2=a_3=1, a_4=1\cdot 1\cdot 2 = 2, a_5=1\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3=6$, seems to be a good sequence.

Comment: Perhaps, it makes sense to look at sequences $\mathbf{b}=(b_n)_{n \ge 0}$ such that for any $m,n\ge 0$, $m\mid n$ implies $b_m\mid b_n$. Then we can let $a_n=n!_\mathbf{b}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}b_k$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein, it seems that your construction *almost* works.  First, apparently $a_n = (n-1)!$ (and $a_0 = 1$) also seems to work, however, for the Fibotorials we have to take $a_n = (n-1)!_{\bf F}$.  Second, if we take $a_n = (n-1)!_{\bf b}$ for a sequence with $m\mid n$ implying $b_m\mid b_n$, it seems that many sequences work, but there are exceptions, for example ${\bf b} = (1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, \dots)$, (so $a_1=a_2=1,\dots,a_7=a_8=16$) it fails for the partition $4,1,1,1,1$, where we would like to have $5a_8 / (a_5 a_4 a_1^4)$ being an integer.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein, I think that your idea works for those sequences where $\binom{a}{b}_{\bf b}$ is an integer.  For ${\bf b} = (1,2,2,2,1,2,1,\dots)$ this is not the case fof $\binom{7}{3}_{\bf b} = \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 1}{(2\cdot 2\cdot 1)\cdot(2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 1)} = \frac{16}{4\cdot 8}$.

Comment: You're right, integer $\mathbf{b}$-binomial coefficients is a better condition.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein: 1. could it be that the "correct" hypothesis for your construction is $b_m\cdot b_n \mid b_{m\cdot n}$? 2. could you turn your construction into an answer (building on the very nice answer of @Oleksandr)?  It is not a necessary condition, but it uncovers many interesting sequences.  For example, I did not know about $a_n = (n-1)!$, but using the OEIS I find many other sequences that seem quite natural.

Comment: This sounds like a nice idea, but it would leave out sequences like the motivating example of the Fibonacci numbers. For example, $F_3=2$ and $F_9=34$, so $F_3^2\not\mid F_9$. Maybe we should restrict it to the case when $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime?

Comment: Corollary 6 of https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL19/Edgar/edgar3.html says that multiplicativity ($b_m\cdot b_n = b_{m\cdot n}$ for coprime $m$ and $n$) together with divisibility ($m\mid n$ implies $b_m\mid b_n$ for all $m$ and $n$) is sufficient.  Knuth and Wilf show that strong divisibility ($\gcd(b_m, b_n) = b_{\gcd(m, n)}$) is also sufficient.  It might be interesting to see how this is related to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Not a definitive answer, but the question is stale, and this could be at least somewhat useful.

Note that we can rewrite the coefficient in the composition as
$$
\left[\frac{z^n}{a_n}\right] F(G(z)) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a_k} \left[\frac{z^k}{a_k}\right] F(z)\left[\frac{z^n}{a_n}\right] G(z)^k,
$$
and for majority of functions of interest we would rather want that groups of summands corresponding to the same partition make up an integer, rather than focusing on an integer total sum. In a very general case, this boils down to a requirement that for any $n$ and a partition $i_1+\dots+i_k = n$, it holds that, assuming $j_t$ is the number of blocks of size $t$, the number

$$
A(i_1,\dots,i_k) = \frac{1}{a_k} \binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k} \frac{a_n}{a_{i_1} \dots a_{i_k}}
$$
is an integer. I suppose, here are some useful properties about such sequences:

1. For $\left[\frac{z^n}{a_n}\right]G(z)=g_n$ and $\left[\frac{z^n}{a_n}\right]F(z)=f_n$, the composition rewrites as
   $$
   \left[\frac{z^n}{a_n}\right] F(G(z)) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty f_k \sum\limits_{\substack{i_1+\dots+i_k=n\\i_1\leq\dots\leq i_k}} A(i_1,\dots,i_k) g_{i_1}\dots g_{i_k},
   $$
   meaning that $A(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ combinatorially stands for the weight with which the corresponding partition of $n$ into $k$ blocks of sizes $i_1,\dots,i_k$ is counted. Typically, this number represents the number of ways to distribute $n$ atoms among the $k$ blocks and/or build some structure on top of the blocks.
2. For $a_n = n!$, we have $A(i_1,\dots,i_k) = \frac{1}{j_1!\dots j_k!} \binom{n}{i_1,\dots,i_k}$, which has  combinatorial meaning as the number of partitions of $n$ into blocks of size $i_1,\dots,i_k$, where order of blocks doesn't matter.
3. For $a_n = x^{n-1}$, we have $A(i_1,\dots,i_k) = \binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k}\frac{1}{x^{k-1}} \frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{n-k}}=\binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k}$.
4. For $a_n = x^{\binom{n}{2}}$, we have
   $$
   A(i_1,\dots,i_k) = \binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k}x^{\binom{n}{2} -\binom{i_1}{2}-\dots-\binom{i_k}{2}-\binom{k}{2}}.
   $$
   At the same time, $\binom{a+b}{2} - \binom{a}{2} - \binom{b}{2} = ab$, from which we can rewrite
   $$
   A(i_1,\dots,i_k) = \binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k}\prod\limits_{a < b} x^{i_a i_b-1},
   $$
   which is always integer if we *only* consider functions $G(x)$ with $G(0)=0$.
5. If $A(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ is always an integer multiple of $\binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k}$, and $b_n$ is a good sequence, then $c_n = a_n b_n$ is also a good sequence, as $C(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ is an integer:
   $$
   C(i_1,\dots,i_k)=\frac{A(i_1,\dots,i_k) B(i_1,\dots,i_k)}{\binom{k}{j_1,\dots,j_k}}
   $$
   For example $c_n = n! 2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ is a good sequence, used to enumerate labeled graphs.

The variant $a_n = x^{\binom{n}{2}}$ is typically used in [graphic generating functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.09454.pdf), and have a nice combinatorial interpretation when considering direct products $F(z) G(z)$, but considering functional composition for them is uncommon, and exact meaning and interpretation for it remains to be seen, if it exists.

**UPD**. Generally, this criterion can be interpreted in such a way that we have some kind of baseline combinatorial structure, such that $a_n$ enumerates the number of way to build the structure on $n$ atoms.

For $a_n=n!$, the structure is permutations, while for $a_n = 2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ the structure is undirected graphs or tournaments on $n$ vertices. Then, the wholeness of $A(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ can be interpreted in such a way that by building the base structure on $n$ atoms, we also implicitly and independently from each other build

1. A sub-structure of the same kind on first $i_1$ atoms, second $i_2$ atoms, and so on;
2. A sub-structure of the same kind on the partition $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$ itself.

Then, $A(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ is the number of $n$-structures that are somehow equivalent to each other with regard to the sub-structures.

Then, we use these baseline structures to build an $F$-structure on top of the composition's base structure, and $G$-structures on top of each block of atoms base structure, and interpret whatever we obtained in the end as an $(F \circ G)$-structure on top of $n$ atoms as a whole.

Comment: Thank you for starting this!  I think in 1. you meant $[z^n/a_n]$, right?  Also, $i_1 + \dots + i_k = n$ should be referred to as a composition of $n$, rather than a partition.

Comment: $z_n / a_n$, yes, thanks for pointing out. And yes, $i_1+\dots+i_k=n$ is actually a composition. Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't think about it this way before, because for $a_n = n!$ we divide it by $k!$, thus accounting for the number of partitions of the atom set, rather than compositions. But in a more generic case it doesn't work like this.

Comment: I think the criterion that $A(\alpha)$ is an integer is too strong, because it does not hold for $a_n = n!$: In this case, $A(1,2) = \frac{a_3}{a_2 a_1 a_2} = \frac{3!}{1! 2!^2} = \frac{3}{2}$.  More precisely, $A(\alpha)$ needs an additional factor, namely the number of rearrangements of $\alpha$, (i.e, the multinomial of the multiplicities of the parts), right?

Comment: In particular, I think that item 2. is incorrect: for example, $a_n = n!^2$ does not work.

Comment: The item 2 is correct if the criterion is for $A(\alpha)$ to be integer... But you're right that it's not and we should additionally account for rearrangements of $\alpha$. I will try to amend my reply.

Comment: I amended the response. Hopefully it makes a bit more sense now.